# Why does my question not appear at the Stack Overflow front page, even two hours after posting?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803135/zanox-api-retrieving-all-adspace) almost 2 hours ago, but it still does not appear at the front page of Stack Overflow.

What is the reason for that? It happened first time and this is why I am not getting any response. I suspect that it's because I have created a new tag [zanox](/questions/tagged/zanox), since it did not exist before. Is it because of that or some other problem?

Comment: Can Any one tell me please what is the reason for downvote this question?

Comment: I don't think deleting the question is the solution - as Pekka suggested, add tag for the language you're using and you should get more views.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok dude but now I have deleted that and I am having less than 10 K reputation. So I cannot undelete that. Thanks for advising. I will take care it in future

Comment: I voted to undelete, you can edit your question here and ask others to vote as well (need total of 3 votes to undelete it)

Comment: So now there are 2 questions. [zanox api Retrieving all adspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803135/zanox-api-retrieving-all-adspace) and [zanox api Retrieving all adspace Not Returing Result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806699/zanox-api-retrieving-all-adspace-not-returing-result)

Comment: @AzizShaikh dude due to two problem. One that First I delted that and second it has some thing different in it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly sure your question appeared on the front page for a while, but the influx of new questions is so great that they disappear from it very quickly. Also note that it takes a few minutes for new questions to come up. I dare say you simply overlooked it, something that can happen easily.

Your specific problem, as you suspect, is that you used very obscure tags: [zanox](/questions/tagged/zanox) (which indeed you created) and [api](/questions/tagged/api). Hardly anybody is going to be subscribed to those tags - this explains the low number of views.

You could consider adding the correct language specific tag as well.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for well explanation. I don't know why other people feel happy to downvote without telling any reason.

Comment: @Awais no problem. Downvoting has a bit of a different function on Meta - like to express disagreement or just minor annoyance. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Check and see if it appeared in the stream of https://stackoverflow.com/questions, as that will give you an idea of when it was posted.  Also, check in your profile to make sure it is posted there.

If all that is okay, see the [blog article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) about how which questions are chosen for the front page.  It's possible since you weren't following the new tag you created that it didn't make your list.  Even if it didn't make your front page, it may have made it onto many other people's lists, as the front page varies from person to person.